# React Native: App get stuck in computing a simple loop on dates using moment

Tags: react-native, expo

I am developing an app using RN which deals a lot with dates. I have a helper function to calculate an array of dates which are the beginnings of weeks between two given dates. I call this helper method in the useEffect function of my screen name SelectWeek. Here is my function:

```
static getWeeks(unixTime) {
    const result = [];
    const createdTime = moment(
      moment(unixTime, "X").format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
      "YYYY-MM-DD"
    );
    const today = moment(new Date()).add(8, "days");
    let temp = createdTime;

    while (temp.format("X") < today.format("X")) {
      result.push(temp.format("jYYYY-jMM-jDD"));
      temp = temp.endOf("week").add(1, "minutes");
    }

    return result;
  }
```

```
export default function SelectWeek(props) {

useEffect(() => {
    const listWeek = TimeHelper.getWeeks(createdTime);
    console.log(listWeek);
  }, []);

return ( // some jsx code )

}
```

The app works fine if the number of weeks is small. But when I add more days to my second date (today), for example if I add 80 days instead of 8, when I want to mount the SelectWeek screen the app freeze and the screen is not mounted. Also the phone start overheating instantly.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm facing a similar problem in my app.

Comment: Not a real Solution, but I found that the moment library is too heavy. I re-wrote all these functions with pure js an using js Date() class and it works fine